# Android Q, get a list of files with MediaStore ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

Per https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#use-cases, once I `targetSdk 29`, the only way to get a list of files from the /Downloads directory is to use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, specifically:

```
// Using the Uri returned from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
DocumentFile dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, uri);
DocumentFile[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Which is fine, but it requires some explicit user action to select and approve it. *(Though this will [further get killed off if targetSdk 30/R](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#file-directory-restrictions).., but that's besides the point for now)*

So how is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files able to still get a list of files from /Downloads without that explicit selection/approval? (it is also `targetSdk 29`)

I tried these methods and they return empty results `"uri empty"`:

```
// 1. uri = MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
// 2. uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        uri, null, null, null,
        DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME + " DESC");
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  // targetSdk 28, I get these results
        final int MAX_RESULTS = 50;
        int colCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        peek.append("uri[").append(rowCount).append(rowCount >= MAX_RESULTS ? "+]" : "]");
        do {
            peek.append("\n=======================================");
            int colPos = cursor.getPosition();
            if (colPos >= MAX_RESULTS) break;
            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                String colName = cursor.getColumnName(i);
                String colVal = cursor.getString(i);
                peek.append("\n").append(colPos).append(".").append(i).append(" ")
                        .append(colName).append("=").append(colVal);
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {  // targetSdk 29, nothing from the cursor/uri
        peek.append("uri empty");
    }
} else {
    peek.append("cursor null");
}
```

*(*note that this is on Emulator Android Q, I don't have a physical Q device)*

And yes, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` granted, and also tried `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

And as expected, the old way to do this also doesn't work:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

*(Of course, when I switch back to `targetSdk 28`, all of the above work again.)*

Am I missing some other API/method? Thanks!

EDIT: added `query` code

Comment: `tried these methods and they return empty results:` No that is not normal. Please post full code.

Comment: Google apps and apps from device manufacturers are not subject to all of the same rules that ordinary apps have to abide by.

Comment: I added the code, and this is on an Emulator Q, I don't have a physical Q device to confirm.

Comment: What is 'an empty result' exactly? A null cursor?

Comment: empty result is `peek.append("uri empty")`

Comment: I tried your query on Android 10 device. I get a lot of junk values.
like instance_id=null
0.1 duration=341
0.2 orientation=null
0.3 format=47362
0.4 height=null
0.5 is_drm=0
0.6 bucket_display_name=ui
0.7 owner_package_name=null
0.8 parent=107
0.9 volume_name=internal
0.10 date_modified=1568668041
0.11 date_expires=null
0.12 _display_name=camera_focus.ogg
0.13 datetaken=null
0.14 mime_type=audio/ogg
0.15 _id=132
0.16 _data=/product/media/audio/ui/camera_focus.ogg
0.17 _hash=null
0.18 _size=11259
0.19 title=camera_focus
0.20 width=null
0.21 is_trashed=0........

Comment: What did you use for your `uri` and are you `targetSdk 29`? *(but yes, my query is meant to return all the columns, junk included)*